# WordPress blank page error

Tags: wordpress, themes

I installed WooCommerce and many plugins. It was all running well. Suddenly I started facing an issue at homepage. I removed everything and restored it by using the backup files taken by duplicator plugin.

I can’t see anything except a blank page. I can’t even access admin panel. Plugins are fine I tested by disabling all. Themes are creating issue. When I disable theme folder by renaming it, admin panel works. When I try to install new theme it doesn’t happen. I can’t even change theme. I don’t know what is exactly the issue.

Comment: Check error log from cpanel. It should have fatal errors logged there.

Comment: Have you checked from your browser's console for any thrown errors? In Chrome or Opera, press `CTRL` + `Shift` + `I` to open it.